# How do you setup spork-rails on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial and my tests are taking forever so I want to implement spork.

Since spork apparently doesn't work for rails anymore I have to do spork-rails instead. I updated my gem file to have spork-rails included and every time I try to run s`pork rspec --bootstrap` the command prompt says `'spork' is not a recognized internal command`.

I took a look at the spork github page and it supports Windows but I can't tell if spork-rails does as well. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the command to execute on Windows you should type: `bundle exec spork rspec --bootstrap`.